# What do these symbols mean? One looks like an inverse "T", another looks like ^

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I saw an equation as the following one. 
[image]

- **What is the meaning of the symbol looking like an inverse T?**
- **How about the symbol "^"?**

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

The following is the context:
[image]
[image]

This is the source:

> *On Updating Problems in Latent Semantic Indexing*, SIAM Journal on Scientific Computing - 21(2):pp. 782-791;

Comment: It might mean [orthogonal complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement), depending on what kind of an object $U_k$ is.

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right. Orthogonal complement is a new concept to me.

Comment: How about the symbol "^"?

Comment: The "^" symbol is not universally defined.  You'll have to reference the text to see exactly what it is.  It may be that they wanted to call the matrix something different so rather than calling it "P" they called it "P hat".

Comment: I agree with @NicNic8, I think "P hat" is just meant to be treated as its own symbol, in much the same way as $x'$ is sometimes used as a symbol distinct from $x$.